# Error "Value of type ... has no member" while calling self in lazy property closure

Tags: swift3, xcode8

Why the following Swift3 code results in error `value of type (NSObject) -> () -> MyView has no member getSomeButton` in Xcode 8?

```
lazy var someButton = {
    return self.getSomeButton // ERROR
}()

private func getSomeButton() -> UIButton {
    return UIButton()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the error message is totally misleading and should be something like `can't infer closure return type`. Specifying variable type solves the problem. Hope this help someone.

```
lazy var someButton: UIButton = {
    return self.getSomeButton // OK
}()
```